# UILocalNotification - alert sound keeps playing after opening app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

Once user opens app from lock screen (swiping push alert - app is in background mode), notification sound keeps playing.

If user opens app from home screen (tapping push alert - app is in background mode), notification sound stops as expected.

Please advise, how to stop the push alert sound in first described scenario.

Thanks.

Schedule

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif.fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotif.alertBody = @"GET THE FLOCK UP!";
localNotif.repeatInterval = 0;
localNotif.hasAction = YES;
localNotif.alertAction = @"GET UP";
localNotif.soundName = @"snooze_wake_push.aif";
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
[app scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

Handling in app delegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

}
```

Comment: it's dup. Solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24530013/751932

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but 99% it is not possible because it is Apple's in-built functionality so best way is stop fighting with it. and may be this problem only occur in simulator not in real device first check on real device.

Comment: It occurs on device. This issue drive me mad. I need the sound stop, once opening app, because I have to play another. App is serving as alarm clock, so after opening app, I need silence push alert sound.

Answer (score 0):

I can reliably repeat this problem with both iPhone and iPad on iOS 7.

There's no programmatic workaround, but if you press the volume up or down button, the notification sound stops.

I've resorted to displaying a hint with the above workaround for users.